# Share workspace, report and app with external user

Tags: powerbi

When I share a workspace with an external user (ie: from another domain), he's unable to see the menu item on the left panel of the screen.

This workspace has me and this other user as admins. We both have Pro Accounts.

He's also unable to view the menu item for the app in this workspace.

However, he can click the URL for the app/report/workspace and see the content.

How to enable these menu items in his account?

Comment: Can you add the user to your domain, using Azure B2B? otherwise you'll have to create a domain account for them

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, must check what Azure B2B is